# Xamarin Android can't deploy on device Error ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException:

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, mobile

I can't deploy my Xamarin Android on my device even I already clear cache memory on this device.
Please anyone help me and what's the problem and how to solve it.

Error       ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output:
Exception occurred while executing 'install':

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you need to look at your device logs

Comment: Can you deploy other apps to your device?  Is there any detailed log about this problem?

Comment: Thank you Jason for your comment and I'll check it now.

Comment: Thank you Jessie Zhang -MSFT for your comment. I've already deployed new project. There is no problem. This project is still problem cannot deploy. I made what mistakes are, I don't know exactly :P